# Existing Java library for getting character offset from line number and column number?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java application that needs to get character offset in bytes, given line number and column number within plain text. I'm wondering if there are existing libraries for doing this since I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks!

Comment: Line and column number of what? Text file, Excel sheet, anything else?

Comment: @AlexR, plain text file.

Comment: How that would work would depend on whether you want to just dip in to random text files or you want to keep a single file and its line offsets in memory so you can efficiently calculate the byte offsets for many line/column pairs.

Comment: Given line number, column _and charset_. If the number of characters is fixed and a charset with a fixed number of bytes per character is used (e.g. ISO-8859-1 -> 1 byte), then it is a simple multiplication. If the character count is variable or the charset uses a variable number of bytes (e.g. UTF-8) it is impossible to calculate, you need to read the file up to the position.

Answer (score 1):

A *character offset in bytes* is a very strange beast. Do you want characters, or do you want bytes? This is a question of encoding. For UTF-8, it even varies for different characters (for `a` it’s one byte, for `ä` two). You’re safe when you use ASCII only, but you did not say that.

If you do use UTF-8, you *must* read the whole file from the beginning to perform this kind of calculation. I am not aware of a library with a function that is that specific, but it’s also easy to do in Java with the proper `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

[InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) has method to skip n bytes. If you want to skip lines with fixed size, you always can calculate number of bytes to skip. Otherwise you need to perform false `nextLine` on `BufferedReader`